# embedding rnn seq2seq and basic rnn seq2seq

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, tensorflow

after reading the documentation and digging for a couple days on the    web i still confused about :

- what is the difference between basic_rnn_seq2seq and
  embedding_rnn_seq2seq?
- And when to use each one of them? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, TensorFlow lacks detailed documentations and examples of their APIs.

I made a brief example for functions in `legacy_seq2seq`.

https://github.com/j-min/tf_tutorial_plus/tree/master/RNN_seq2seq/legacy_seq2seq

Comment: Hello j-min, thanks for the example.i've read it and that helped me to understand some things. I still have an issue, in your example a sentence is converted to one vector .In my case each example is a matrix with a fixed number of columns but variable number of rows.eg:([5,5,9,7,2],[1,5,8,7,9]) is one input and ([2,5,7,9,6][2,9,7,5,6][1,0,3,6,7]) is another one that has same number of columns as the previous but a different number of rows. how to feed that to my seq2seq model.

Comment: You can pad all inputs and give padding information to RNNs via `sequence_length` so that it ignores each batch if current time step is greater than predetermined length. That is how [tf.nn.dynamic_rnn](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn) or [tf.contrib.seq2seq.decoder dynamic_decode](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/seq2seq/dynamic_decode) work.
The core of these APIs are [tf.TensorArray](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/TensorArray) and [tf.while_loop](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/while_loop).

Comment: Thank you , i will try that and come back to you